# Can amsbook produce a Table of Contents with no page numbers?

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

I have a book in progress, using amsbook.  I want to show people a table of contents. But the current page numbers would be entirely misleading since the sections are very roughly sketched now, not fully written.

Can I get amsbook to generate a TOC with no page numbers?

Answer (score 3):

The page numbers in the ToC is formatted using `\@tocpagenum`. So, just redefine it to grab its argument and do nothing with it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Avoid page numbers from being printed in ToC
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocpagenum}[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\sloppy% Just for this example
\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[1-25]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[1-25]

\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[1-25]

\chapter{Final chapter}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[1-25]

\end{document}
```